# CSS: How to create this kind of Fade In Down animation

Tags: css, css-transitions, css-animations

How to create this kind of css animation where element fades in from the bottom but appears like clipped with overflow:

http://fr.creasenso.com/ (see the breadcrumb text)

I've tried all the basics but not going anywhere with translateY. Do I need to go to libraries or is it achievable with css only?

Comment: Read [ask] for tips on improving the quality of your question(s). The current one doesn't show any research effort. Consider creating a [mcve] and letting us in on what you tried, expected to work, but didn't. In a nutshell, people here are not ready to code for you. In fact, I'd say they're reluctant to do so. They are here to help you learn to code yourself. So help them help you and show signs that you are ready to learn. Asking for code is not the proper way to ask on [so], IMHO.

Comment: Ok I just realised translateY does not work with list elements at all apparently. Still a good example of this would be ABSOLUTELY FANTASTIC as I never have managed to find one.

Comment: Actually, that's wrong. `translateY` works on any element, as long as it has a set `position` other than `static`.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu `translateY` works on statically positioned elements too. It's the `top, left...` properties...

Comment: @user31782 You are correct. Thank for your comment. I was sure it needed positioning. You gave me a research subject for today. :)

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu It is `transform` which has more stuff like `scale, rotate` etc. The `top, left, right, bottom` properties work with positioned elements(fixed, absolute or sticky). You are welcome ;-)

Comment: @user31782 I know what `transform` is and does. What it actually needs is  `display` other than `inline`, `run-in`, `contents` and a few others, couldn't find the entire list. My upper-floor-department was re-decorating while I requested the above information earlier on and they apparently served it from the wrong drawer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The wording of your question could use some improvement. But besides that, I think this is what you are looking for:

https://jsfiddle.net/5ws33c8s/

You need a parent element which has a `overflow: hidden`. Followed by the childs which are moved out using `translate: translateY()`. 
I then used css keyframes to move it back in:

```
animation: fadeInText 300ms 0ms forwards;

@keyframes fadeInText {
  from {
    transform: translateY(30px);
    opacity: 0;
  } to {
    transform: translateY(0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

This animation is set up as follows; `fadeInText` is the keyframes name, `300ms` is the duration of the animation, `0ms` is the delay of said animation and `forwards` remembers the final state of the animation, and leaves the element as such. Without it, the element would jump back to its original values.
I then used a delay on each child element.

```
span:nth-child(2) {
  animation-delay: 150ms;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Mitchel. Just absolutely going nuts about this... But thanks that works. The problem ended up being missing inline-block with the li element